# Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « passer à la casserole » avec « coïter » ?

Tags: étymologie

[Ce site Web](http://www.cuisineaz.com/articles/que-signifie-l-expression-passer-a-la-casserole-630.aspx) prétend deux origines qui n'expliquent pas assez le glissement sémantiquement entre [le sens littéral](http://www.doctissimo.fr/sexualite/diaporamas/expressions-erotiques-qu-on-utilise-sans-le-savoir/passer-a-la-casserole) et celui lascif.

> Comme souvent, avec bien des expressions, on a perdu la trace de l'évolution de son sens. Tout ce que l'on sait, c'est qu'à l'origine, **[Proposition 1.]** "passer à la casserole" désignait le moment de la mise à mort pour les poules dont on estimait que la carrière de pondeuse était terminée ! **[Fin de 1.]**
>
> #### Les poules en fin de carrière passaient à la casserole
>
> Mais l'expression pourrait aussi provenir d'une autre expression courant au XIXe siècle : "faire un tour à la casserole". **[Proposition 2.]**  À l'époque, "faire un tour à la casserole" désignait, sans que l'on ne sache trop pourquoi, le traitement antivénérien, destiné à lutter contre une maladie sexuellement transmissible. **[Fin de 2.]** Tous les ingrédients sont là, mais il nous manque, et manquera peut-être toujours, la recette qui a permis d'en arriver à ce que "passer à la casserole" désigne l'acte sexuel...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voici en premier lieu une explication sur le *sans que l'on sache trop pourquoi* de la proposition 2.

Au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, l'un des seuls traitements utilisés contre la syphilis consistait à badigeonner les patients de mercure, produit malheureusement très toxique et sans efficacité pour cette pathologie. Ce traitement était prodigué à l'Hôpital du midi (aujourd'hui [Hôpital Cochin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B4pital_Cochin)).

D'autre part, l'étain était utilisé à l'époque (et [encore aujourd'hui](https://www.etamage-casserole.com/)) pour recouvrir l'intérieur des casseroles en cuivre d'une couche protectrice et éviter ainsi que s'y forme du vert-de-gris très toxique.

L'expression *passer à la casserole* est née de l'assimilation entre l'application de l'étain dans les casseroles et l'application de mercure sur les zones infectées des patients.

On a d'abord commencé à appeler le traitement *être étamé*, puis *passer à la casserole*.

*La casserole* a aussi fini par désigner l'hôpital du Midi lui-même.

Aujourd'hui, « passer à la casserole » ne désigne pas l'acte sexuel lui-même, mais, pour l'un des partenaires (celui qui « passe à la casserole ») le fait de subir un rapport sexuel, souvent le premier, de manière peu ou pas consentie. Ceci inclut donc aussi les situations de viol.

Il est donc assez facile d'imaginer la dérive sémantique de l'expression. Le traitement n'était certainement pas agréable ni anticipé. Les patients devaient se déshabiller et leurs partie intimes étaient « agressées » par le badigeonnage de mercure.

Source: *Dictionnaire étymologique de mille et une expressions propres à l'idiome français*, Adrien Timmermans, 1846